# Twitter API - Pulling a value from a large array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, api, twitter

Here is the the first part of the array I have returned from a twitter API call. I'm trying to extract the  [expanded_url] variable and store it into another array. I have it working for the top level items such as [id] or [text], but I'm not sure how to access the deeper elements.

```
Array
(
    [statuses] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [metadata] => Array
                    (
                        [iso_language_code] => en
                        [result_type] => recent
                    )

                [created_at] => Thu Mar 26 21:02:42 +0000 2015
                [id] => 581199619855650816
                [id_str] => 581199619855650816
                [text] => RT @JamilSays: 150 people recently died in a plane crash, ISIS is beheading innocent people, and you guys are bitching over Zayn leaving 1Dâ€¦
                [source] => Twitter for iPhone
                [truncated] => 
                [in_reply_to_status_id] => 
                [in_reply_to_status_id_str] => 
                [in_reply_to_user_id] => 
                [in_reply_to_user_id_str] => 
                [in_reply_to_screen_name] => 
                [user] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 546187115
                        [id_str] => 546187115
                        [name] => Medina âœ¨
                        [screen_name] => Medinabtnc
                        [location] => 
                        [profile_location] => 
                        [description] => Bosnia and Herzegovina // Belgium // FC BAYERN MÃœNCHEN â™¡
                        [url] => http://t.co/z1LwFoDZ6U
                        [entities] => Array
                            (
                                [url] => Array
                                    (
                                        [urls] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [url] => http://t.co/z1LwFoDZ6U
                                                        [expanded_url] => http://izzzyyxo.tumblr.com
                                                        [display_url] => izzzyyxo.tumblr.com
                                                        [indices] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [0] => 0
                                                                [1] => 22
                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                                [description] => Array
                                    (
                                        [urls] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                            )
```

Here is the code I'm using to access and echo the [id]. I need to modify it to find the [expanded_url]

```
foreach($string['statuses'] as $items)
    {

        echo  $items['id']."<br />";
    }
```

Once I'm able to fine the [expanded_url] in the loop I'd like to store each URL to an array if possible!

Comment: Have you, by any chance, added more brackets or changed brackets in your echo statement? For instance `$items['user']`?

Comment: I end up with Notice: Array to string conversion in /home2/chrisvad/public_html/twitterstuff.php on line 37
Array
Array
Array
Array
Array
Array
Array
Array
Array
Array
Array
Array
Array
Array
Array

Comment: I tried:  echo  $items['user']['entities']['url']['urls']['expanded_url']."<br />"; but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be working for the most part, although sometimes it does caus an error.

```
foreach($string['statuses'] as $items)
{
    if($items['user']['entities']['url']['urls']['0']['expanded_url'] !="")
    echo  $items['user']['entities']['url']['urls']['0']['expanded_url']."<br />";
```